# How to disable modifier calculations while in edit mode?

Tags: modifiers, performance

I'm working in a project with many boolean modifiers, so the performance when I edit a mesh (that is affected or affecting by all these modifiers) completely freezes my computer for several seconds every time I drag anything.

I noticed that disabling the `viewport realtime` toggle in the modifiers do **not** actually disable realtime calculations,

So the only workaround I found is going modifier by modifier removing the target object, making edits to the mesh, and then re-associate all the modifier target objects. Which as you may guess it is not very user friendly nor time efficient.

Is there a way to make the modifiers only to recalculate on exiting the edit more? or to actually disable modifiers temporally?

Thanks!

Comment: In a simple situation, disabling viewport display of the modifier **does** disable calculation.  I tested this, in 3.0, by testing with a couple of subdivided UV spheres with boolean difference.  There could be some details specific to your situation that change that-- but then, we'd need to know those details.

Comment: I'm still in 2.x, I will try 3.0.
Do you know which kind of "situations"?
thanks

Comment: I'm now in 3.0.1, realtime-disabled bool modifiers are still being recalculated in realtime in edit mode :'(

Comment: Then like I said, there could be some details specific your situation that change that, but we'd need to know those details.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Nathan, I created a new project, all preferences are fresh from 3.0, I create 2 spheres, apply subdivision to both (enough to stress the cpu), add bool modifier, go into edit mode, drag vert, dragging is slow (bool being recalculated), then for comparison disable bool realtime and is dragging still slow, and finally with bool target removed (so it is modifier is actually skipped) dragging is back to normal. This kinda tell that modifier realtime toggle does not really stop calculations, but just do not draw them in the viewport? Is this expected behaviour or a bug?

Comment: The dragging is probably not slow because of your boolean, but because of live subdivision.  Check out https://pasteall.org/blend/a366014b74954ef09a9e1ae1f661b3a9, which has an animation, incl. animated viewport visibility of a boolean, which should make the performance difference clear.  It's set to a fast solver, but it's the same with exact solver (only slower, while the boolean is in operation.)

Comment: But in future, just link a file.  When people are asking questions, it's almost always because there's something they don't understand.  The problem is, when they don't understand a problem, they can't distinguish between details relevant to that problem and details that aren't.  Linking a file lets people who can distinguish rapidly identify the cause.

Comment: Submitting a project file would be tricky because getting to the point in which the cpu struggles would vary depending on the pc. In any case I found an alternative workaround by using "hide in viewport" checkmark in the outliner, so it is equivalent to actually disabling all the modifiers of the problematic object while working in another one.